# how to call the array in $$variable

Tags: php

```
$var = "array";
$$var=array("1","2");
```

How can I call the array in `$$var` without using `foreach`? I want a method like `$$var[0]`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: using variable variables is rarely a good idea.. use a better data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
echo ${$var}[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run this piece of code:

```
$var = "array";
$$var = array("1","2");
```

...it is identical to this:

```
$array = array("1","2");
```

So you can do this:

```
echo $array[0];
```

...or this:

```
echo ${$var}[0];
```

If you *must* use variable variables - and 99.99% of the time arrays are a better solution - you should always use braces for clarity and disambiguation.

See the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) reference for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need some curly braces:

```
${$var[1]}
```

OR

```
${$var}[1]
```

depending on which variable you are accessing.